# Google Maps Geocoding XML service returns error via Curl when city name with more than 1 word is used

Tags: google-maps, curl, geocoding

I am using the following Google Maps Geocoding service via a php script

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=

I have already tried curl and file_get_contents but none of them worked. The problem is when I use city name with one word it works but when I use city name with two words then I do not get anything back from the service but the following error

1. That’s an error.

Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.

Below is some code snippet from the script

$city = $_GET["c"];
$url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=$city&sensor=false";
$data = curl_download($url);
//$data = file_get_contents($url);

echo $data;

I have also uploaded the script to the location below

01)http://www.javeria.com/sites/travel/map/googlemap.php?c=Houston (works)
02)http://www.javeria.com/sites/travel/map/googlemap.php?c=New+York (does not work)

When invoked with 02) it won't display the map instead I am masking the error to display a user friendly message.

I would appreciate any help into this matter.

Comment: mmmm, I tried invoke the url you provide from your script and it works using _New York_ as city parameter  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=new%20york&sensor=false

Comment: It works when you directly invoke it like below

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=New+york

But when you use curl or file_get_contents() it does not work

see the link below that does not work

http://www.javeria.com/sites/travel/map/googlemap.php?c=New+York 

but if you do 

http://www.javeria.com/sites/travel/map/googlemap.php?c=Houston

it works

Comment: I managed to get it to work. Here is what I did

01) from the given address replace 'spaces' with '+'
02) urlencode address
03) Pass the url to curl

Below is an example that works if address has spaces in it

http://www.javeria.com/sites/travel/map/googlemap.php?c=New%2BYork

Answer (score 2):

Try using `+` between the words. I am doing essentially the same thing - and that change makes it work for me.